# MongoDB different query styles with different results

Tags: mongodb

I have a document :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5324d5b30cf2df0b84436141"),
    "value": 0,
    "metaId": {
        "uuid": "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1",
        "domain": "domain1"
    }
}
```

Also I have ensured indexes of this type:

```
 ensureIndex({"metaId.uuid" : 1})
```

Now here comes two queries:

1. > `db.test.find({"metaId" : {"uuid" : "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1"}}).explain()`

   `"cursor" : "BasicCursor"`

   *NO Index used!*
2. > `db.test.find({"metaId.uuid" : "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1"}).explain()`

   `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor metaId.uuid_1"`

   *Index used!*

Is there a way to make both queries use index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue on this, [SERVER-2953](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2953). You can vote that up if you wish.

In the meantime you could do this instead:

```js
{
    "value": 0,
    "metaId": [{
        "uuid": "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1",
        "domain": "domain1"
    }]
}
```

And with a *slightly* different query form then the index **will** be selected:

```js
db.test.find(
    {"metaId" : { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "uuid" : "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1"
        }
    }}
).explain()
```

And actually that query **will** match the index with your current data form as well. However it will not return results. But with the data in this form it will return a match.

It is generally better to use an array element with a *"contained"* sub-document, even if it is only **one**. This allows for much more flexible searching, especially if you want to expand on the different field keys in the sub-document in the future.

Comment: Yea, thanks. Already saw this solution somewhere else. However it's much more convenient for me to make these kind of queries since this is exactly how I store data in Mongo. Hope my vote will count

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the following document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5324d5b30cf2df0b84436141"),
    "value": 0,
    "metaId": {
        "uuid": "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1",
        "domain": "domain1"
    }
}
```

Would not match the Query:

```
db.test.find({
    "metaId": {
        "uuid": "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1"
    }
});
```

Because, it's querying by the value of "metaId" which has to match exactly to:

```
{
    "uuid": "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1",
    "domain": "domain1"
}
```

In this case, you'd be using the index on "metaId".

Comment: You are right, without specifying the domain it will not return this document, however you are wrong it will not hit an Index

   db.test.find({"metaId" : {
        "uuid" : "8df088b2-9aa1-400a-8766-3080a6206ed1",
        "domain" : "domain1"
    }}).explain()